# What is the full title of this patent application US 2014/0276500 A1? Is it still pending review?

Tags: legal-status, medical, us20140276500

In reference to the patent: [US 2014/0276500 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140276500)

What is the full title of this patent application?

Is it still pending review?

Answer (score 1):

I think Google Patents has the application title correct: `Medical device, method of making and using the same`. However, that does sound more like the title of a patent class, not a patent application.

This was the title from the original specification document (March 12, 2014):

---

[image: Original Specification Title]

---

However, a revised specification (April 4, 2014) provided a new title: "Ostomy Protection Device":

---

[image: Revised Specification Title]

---

Ultimately, when the application published on September 18, 2014, the original title was used:

---

[image: Notice of Publication]

---

No further events have transpired on this patent, so it is still pending (see USPTO Public Pair, search by *Publication Number* **US 20140276500 A1**) and look at the Image File Wrapper.